# Oracle SQL, calculating next order qty based on order history

Tags: sql, oracle, prediction, trend

I am using the following script to get the order history of a particular manufacturing order;

```
select ds.status, ds.catnr, ds.part_no, ds.print_type, ds.nr_discs, ds.qty, ds.ship_date 
from
(select 'Open Order' status, gb.catnr, gb.part_no, decode(gb.tec_criteria,'XX','SCREEN','OF','OFFSET','PI','OFFSET','MC','OFFSET') print_type, sp.nrunits nr_discs, sum(gb.or_menge_fd) qty, min(trunc(gb.shd_date)) ship_date 
from gps_beweg gb, oes_customer oc, scm_packtyp sp
where gb.part_no = 'A0101628358-VV92-1900' 
and gb.uebergabe_oes = '1'
and gb.pwerk_disc = 'W'
and gb.cunr = oc.cunr
and gb.packtyp = sp.packtyp
group by gb.cunr, oc.name, gb.part_no, sp.nrunits, gb.tec_criteria, gb.catnr, gb.prodtyp, gb.packtyp
UNION ALL
select unique 'Shipped Order' status, 
null catnr, null part_no, null print_type, null nr_discs, 
(select sum(ds1.planqty) from oes_delsegview ds1 where ds.ordnr = ds1.ordnr and ds.catnr = ds1.catnr and ds.prodtyp = ds1.prodtyp and ds.packtyp = ds1.packtyp) qty,
(select trunc(max(ds1.gps_planshpdate)) from oes_delsegview ds1 where ds.ordnr = ds1.ordnr and ds.catnr = ds1.catnr and ds.prodtyp = ds1.prodtyp and ds.packtyp = ds1.packtyp) ship_date
from part_description pd1, oes_delsegview ds
where pd1.part_no =
    (select max(gb.part_no) 
        from gps_beweg gb
        where gb.part_no = 'A0101628358-VV92-1900' 
        and gb.uebergabe_oes = '1'
        and gb.pwerk_disc = 'W')
and pd1.catnr = ds.catnr
and pd1.prodtyp = ds.prodtyp
and pd1.packtyp = ds.packtyp
and ds.ord_o_status in ('7','9')
order by status, ship_date desc) ds
where rownum <=5
```

The result for this script looks like this...

[image]

I would like to use the data in the QTY and SHIP_DATE column to predict the next qty and date. I can do this in Excel using the TREND function. Is there a way of doing this in SQL? Will it be in line with the REGR_SLOPE function (I can't seem to get my head around how this works!?!).

Comment: As far as I know there is nothing built in Oracle's SQL to help you here. There exists a forecast report function though: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_commands_1052.htm#OLADM822. I've never used this and actually wouldn't know how to invoke it. You may be able to use this somehow or do that outside the DBMS with Excel or whatever tool providing the functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I will check out the forecast function (thanks for the link). I think I may have to revert back to using the Excel functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, as far as I know Oracle's SQL has no built-in trend functions to help you here.  What you could do, though, is to to play around with analytic functions and come up with some algorithm.

`ship_date - LAG(ship_date) OVER (ORDER BY ship_date)` gives you the days between last and current order for instance. You'd have to weight these values, however, say multiply them with `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ship_date)`. Then divide to get the value to add to `MAX(ship_date)`.

Here is the according query. A little hard to read and understand, but still an option in my opinion. The query retrieves all rows from yours plus a trend date and quantity for each row. So you can see what would have been forcast at some time and what shipment really followed. The last row gives you the current forecast.

```
select 
  status, catnr, part_no, print_type, nr_discs, qty, ship_date, 
  round(qty + sum(qty_diff_weighted) over (order by rn) /
    (sum(rn) over (order by rn) - 1)) as trend_qty,   
  round(ship_date + sum(date_diff_weighted) over (order by rn) /
    (sum(rn) over (order by rn) - 1)) as trend_date   
from
(
  select 
    status, catnr, part_no, print_type, nr_discs, qty, ship_date,
    row_number() over (order by ship_date) *
      (qty - lag(qty) over (order by ship_date)) as qty_diff_weighted,
    row_number() over (order by ship_date) *
      (ship_date - lag(ship_date) over (order by ship_date)) as date_diff_weighted,
    row_number() over (order by ship_date) as rn
  from (your query)
)
order by ship_date;
```

Result:

```
STATUS          CATNR   ...   QTY   SHIP_DATE    TREND_QTY   TREND_DATE
Shipped Order                 500   06.06.2014
Shipped Order                 500   17.11.2014   500         30.04.2015
Shipped Order                 300   21.09.2015   180         28.05.2016
Shipped Order                 300   16.08.2016   233         29.05.2017
Open Order      PPD168        300   24.03.2017   257         11.12.2017
```

This shows the technique. You may come up with a completely different algorithm that suits you better, of course.

Comment: These results are not far off the results I was getting from Excel TREND...I may test some different algorithms, but I really appreciate the advice. This has definitely pointed me in the right direction. Thank you.